# Dask map_overlap passes partitions in non-chronological order

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Dask's `df.map_overlap()` function passes the partitions in non chronological order. This is extremely inefficient for computations on large datasets with a lot of overlap. Of course, we are running parallelized anyway, so the order of operations is not guaranteed, but this seems like a design flaw that contributes to a higher than necessary memory load. Does anyone have an idea of how this could be solved? Here is a MVE that prints the start and end dates. You can see that the ordering seems to be random. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

date_range = pd.date_range(start='2023-06-01', end='2023-07-01', freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': date_range,
    'quantity': np.random.rand(len(date_range))
})

df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=5)
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.ceil('1h')
df = df.set_index('timestamp', sorted=True)

df = df.repartition(freq='1h')

def custom_func(ser):
    print(f'from: {ser.index.min()}, to: {ser.index.max()}')
    return pd.Series(np.mean(ser), index=ser.index)

results = df['quantity'].map_overlap(custom_func, before=pd.Timedelta(days=7), after=0, meta=pd.Series(dtype='float64'), align_dataframes=False, enforce_metadata=False).drop_duplicates()

results.compute()
```

Comment: "df.map_overlap() function passes the partitions in non chronological order" - do you have proof of this? When each input partition is needed by multiple partitions in the next step, they should stay around in worker memory or maybe transferred rather than be recalculated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but hopefully gives you some promising directions to explore.

It's possible to construct a custom DAG that satisfies your desired ordering. Assuming your data is indexed/order, you can use the explicit partition ranges to run the computations. For example:

```py
from dask import compute
from dask.datasets import timeseries
df = timeseries(end='2000-01-10')

n_partitions = df.npartitions
days_offset = 7
partition_combinations = [(i-days_offset, i) for i in range(n_partitions) if i-days_offset>=0]

all_results = []
for start, end in partition_combinations:
   print(start, end)
   subset_result = df.partitions[start:end].mean()
   all_results.append(subset_result)

computed = compute(*all_results)
```

Note that there is no `.map` or `.map_overlap` used since we are explicitly controlling the range of partitions used in a calculation. After all the lazy/delayed computations are formed, the last line will trigger the actual computations.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have tried this approach before, but could not implement this with a custom function. Taking the mean of the entire period was just an example. In reality, I want to do more complex operations on the entire series. 

Therefore df.partitions[start:end].apply(custom_func) is necessary. However, apply will only apply the function to each partition separately, not across all selected partitions simultaneously